# Remember a previous location of a player object

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stddraw

Ok, so I am trying to create a program where, using scanner, if the user types "up", "down", "left", or "right", the shape will move accordingly. I got the shape to move as the words say, but whenever I enter a new command, I cannot get the program to remember where the shape was before the new command was given. The shape starts off at a 0,0 every time I enter a new direction. Here is what I have so far, I believe the problem is with my y-coordinate:

```
 double location = 0;
 double prev = 0;     
 for (double i = -10; i <= 10; i++) // for the scale that was set 
 {
  String word = in.nextLine(); // new string: word = user typed

  if (word.equals("up")) // if word = up, move player up
  {
    location ++;
    prev -= location;
    StdDraw.clear();
    drawTarget(a);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
    StdDraw.filledCircle(prev, location, 0.5);

  }

 else if (word.equals("down")) // if word = down, move player down
  {
    location--;
    prev += location;
    StdDraw.clear();
    drawTarget(a);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
    StdDraw.filledCircle(prev, location, 0.5);

  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you also include where you're initializing "location" and "prev" values as well?  It'd help in figuring the issue out.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to increment a value to move something from a previous location to a new location, but you're basing the circle that gets drawn on both the previous and new location?  I don't see how the previous location factors into the circle that gets drawn.

Comment: So if I completely remove the "prev" variable, what would I replace it with?

Comment: filledCircle() accepts arguments for the x-coordinate of the circle to draw, the y-coordinate, and the radius.  Since you're setting "prev" based on location, both of those things are going to change (as a function of location).  If you're just looking to move up or down (and not on a 2D plane), the x-coordinate can stay the same and the y-coordinate can vary accordingly.

Comment: what if I need to go left? What would prev be then?

Comment: It would be whatever the new x-coordinate needs to be.  You don't base what you're drawing on where it was, it should be based purely on where you want it to display.  It might make more sense to rename "location" to "yCoordinate" and "prev" to "xCoordinate"